# php - based on mysql exclude key from array and echo rest

Tags: mysql, arrays

In mysql table i got entries with those keys should be exclude from the array.

How to echo all array keys without those specifed in mysql table?

```
<?php
    $a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
?>
```

In table i have entries with key that should be exlude from array

```
<?php
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT key FROM table");
    while($get=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $k=$get['key'];
    }
?>
```

Now i need each $k exclude from $a array and echo all others array keys.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT key FROM table");
    while($get=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $k=$get['key'];
        // check $k exists in $a array or not
        if(in_array($k, $a)){
            //get array index here
            $i = array_search($k, $a);
            unset($a[$i]); 
        }
    }
    print_r($a);

?>
```

It will print array values which are not found in table

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check if current key exists in array.

```
if( in_array($get['key'], $a) ) {
    continue; // if key exists in $a, skip current iteration
}
```